# Ignoring exceptions in VS 2022 MAUI Android doesn't work

Tags: android, visual-studio-2022, maui

There are some exceptions when debugging .NET MAUI on Android which are harmless and I want to ignore them.

For example `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` during startup, somewhere in MAUI libraries possibly.

[image: Exception example]

Eventhough the exceptions IS ignored in VS **Exception Settings** the debugger still breaks on the exceptions for some reason. This happens only in a MAUI project.

[image: Ignored exception]

If I choose to **ignore all CLR exceptions** then all exceptions are really ignored...but that's hardly what I want, I just want to ignore this particular exception which is not ignored eventhough it's unchecked.

Has anyone found a way to make VS correctly ignore exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Current Visual Studio IDE can ignore specific exceptions as required.

The steps is :

`Debug`-->`Windows`-->`Exception settings`

You can record the previous exception's name and search under it and then uncheck it.

After that, please uncheck Just My Code option, otherwise the exception may still be interrupted.

`Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`-->`Just My Code`

Comment: Even with Just My Code unchecked and the exception unchecked in the exception settings, the debugger still stops on the exception :(